# Codeigniter - reverse data in table

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm look for a way to display data in reverse order using the table library along with pagination in Codeigniter.  From

```
public function pagination(){

    $this->load->library("pagination");
    $this->load->library("table");

    $this->table->set_heading("ID", "Name", "Address");

    $config["base_url"] = site_url('site/pagination');
    $config["total_rows"] = $this->db->get("mail")->num_rows();
    $config["per_page"] = 10;
    $config["num_links"] = 10;
    $config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;


    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $data["records"] = $this->db->get("mail", $config["per_page"], $this->input->get('per_page', TRUE)); 
    $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    $this->load->view("site_header");
    $this->load->view("site_nav");
    $this->load->view("content_about", $data);
    $this->load->view("site_footer");

}
```

The table is working just fine but i can't figure out a way to display the data in reverse order. I would like to make the table start with the latest entries (ID, Name, Address) from the database and not the first.

I suppose their i something wrong with how i query the database:
$data["records"] = $this->db->get("mail", $config["per_page"], $this->input->get('per_page', TRUE));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change :

```
$data["records"] = $this->db->get("mail", $config["per_page"], $this->input->get('per_page', TRUE));
```

to :

```
$data["records"] = $this->db->select("ID, Name, Address")->from("mail")->order_by("ID DESC")->limit($config["per_page"], $offset)->result_array();
```

Answer (score 1):

only add in your model

```
$this->db->order_by('id', 'asc');//or desc
```